# Open a page programmatically in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2, mechanize

Can you extract the VIN number from this [webpage](https://www.iaai.com/Vehicles/VehicleDetails.aspx?auctionID=14712591&itemID=15775059&RowNumber=0)?

I tried `urllib2.build_opener`, requests, and mechanize. I provided user-agent as well, but none of them could see the VIN.

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent',('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) ' 'AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' 'Chrome/13.0.782.13 Safari/535.1'))]
page = opener.open(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

table = soup.find('dd', attrs = {'class': 'tip_vehicleStats'})
vin = table.contents[0]
print vin
```

Comment: What do you get? The whole page?

Comment: I get an empty span class, but actually the VIN number should be there. You can see it when inspecting the element in the browser.

Comment: @TeodorScorpan It's dynamically created using Javascript.

Comment: You are saying there's no way I can scrap it?

Comment: A good way to test whether something is normally scrapeable is to view it in your browser with JavaScript turned off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use browser automation tools for the purpose.

For example this simple selenium script can do your work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.iaai.com/Vehicles/VehicleDetails.aspx?auctionID=14712591&itemID=15775059&RowNumber=0"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(link)
page = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

table = soup.find('dd', attrs = {'class': 'tip_vehicleStats'})
vin = table.contents.span.contents[0]
print vin
```

BTW, `table.contents[0]` prints the entire span, including the span tags.

`table.contents.span.contents[0]` prints only the VIN no.

Answer (score 7):

That page has much of the information loaded and displayed with Javascript (probably through Ajax calls), most likely as a direct protection against scraping. To scrape this you therefore either need to use a browser that runs Javascript, and control it remotely, or write the scraper itself in javascript, or you need to deconstruct the site and figure out exactly what it loads with Javascript and how, and see if you can duplicate these calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lennart Regebro. It sounds tough to implement. =)

Comment: @TeodorScorpan Well, I sure as heck wouldn't want to implement a scraper in Javascript. :-) But if you debug the javascript it may be that the actual calls are simple Ajax calls. That's your best bet, I think.

Comment: Do you have any example or tutorial showing how to 'deconstruct the site and ..duplicate these calls...' I have that behind my mind for a while and never see any real life success.

Comment: @B.Mr.W. No, you just have to debug the Javascript on the site and see what Ajax calls are being done, and see if you can duplicate those.

Answer (score 2):

You could use selenium, which calls a browser. This works for me :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242794/open-a-page-programatically-in-python
browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("https://www.iaai.com/Vehicles/VehicleDetails.aspx?auctionID=14712591&itemID=15775059&RowNumber=0") # Load page


time.sleep(0.5) # Let the page load


# Search for a tag "span" with an attribute "id" which contains "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_VINc_VINLabel"
e=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@id,'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_VINc_VINLabel')]")
e.text
# Works for me : u'4JGBF7BE9BA648275'

browser.close()
```

Comment: I posted this at the same time as shshank. Basically, it's the same idea : use selenium.

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to use Selenium. 
Just make an additional get request:

```
import requests

stock_number = '123456789'        # located at VEHICLE INFORMATION  
url = 'https://www.clearvin.com/ads/iaai/check?stockNumber={}&vin='.format(stock_number)
vin = requests.get(url).json()['car']['vin']
```